# Why doesn't this simple_html_dom selector work when used in entirety but not when broken into smaller selectors?

Tags: php, dom, simple-html-dom

I'm having a go scraping a page with [simple_html_dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/). On the page I'm scraping, there's a table with rows, and inside those, a bunch of cells. I'm wanting to get stuff in the third cell in each row. The cell in question doesn't have a class.

```
<tr class="thisrow">
  <td class="firstcell"><strong>1st</strong></td>
  <td class="secondcell">nothing in here</td>
  <td><strong>blah blah</strong></td>
  <td>something else</td>
</tr>
```

So to get started, I went straight for the third cell:

```
foreach($html->find('tr.thisrow td:nth-child(3)') as $thirdcell) {
    echo $thirdcell->innertext // this works, no problem!
}
```

But then I realised I needed some data in another cell in the row (td.firstcell). This cell has a class, so I thought best to loop through the rows, then use selectors within the context of that row:

```
foreach($html->find('tr.thisrow') as $row) {

    $thirdcell = $row->find('td:nth-child(3)');
    echo $thirdcell; // this is now empty

    $firstcell = $row->find('td.firstcell');
    echo $firstcell; // this works!

}
```

So as you can see, my nth-child selector suddenly inside the context of the row loop is not working. What am I missing?

Comment: could you add the target html for test?

Comment: @smoqadam, sure, thanks, I added it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a limitation of `simple html dom`. Apparently it can deal with `nth-child` selectors, but only when the parent is in the tree below the node on which you apply `find`.

But it is a valid selector, as the equivalent JavaScript shows:

```js
for (var row of [...document.querySelectorAll('tr.thisrow')]) {
    var thirdcell = row.querySelectorAll('td:nth-child(3)');
    console.log(thirdcell[0].textContent); // this works!
}
```

```html
<table border=1>
<tr class="thisrow">
  <td class="firstcell"><strong>1st</strong></td>
  <td class="secondcell">nothing in here</td>
  <td><strong>blah blah</strong></td>
  <td>something else</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

As a workaround you could use the array index on the `find('td')` result:

```
foreach($html->find('tr.thisrow') as $row) {
    $thirdcell = $row->find('td');
    echo $thirdcell[2]; // this works
}
```

Or, alternatively with `children`, as `td` are direct children of `tr`:

```
foreach($html->find('tr.thisrow') as $row) {
    $thirdcell = $row->children();
    echo $thirdcell[2]; // this works
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining that, and also teaching a really good way to check if my selector is right! I never would have imagined it was a limitation in the package.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `children($int)` method. `$int` start with `0`.

try this :

```
$row = $html->find('tr.thisrow',0);

$firstcell = $row->children(2)->innertext;
$thirdcell = $row->children(0)->innertext;
```

also you have : `first_child ()` , `last_child()`, `parent()`,`next_sibling()`,`prev_sibling()`